# Make Image drag, rotate and scale more slowly while still being smooth

Tags: android, canvas, scale

I have these ImageViews:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBgHand"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRingPinky"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />
```

And I've set to ivRingPinky onTouchListener(), but before that, I have applied the following animation

```
    Animation zoomIn,
    zoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.iv_zoom_in_1_finger);
    ivBgHand.startAnimation(zoomIn);
    ivRingPinky.startAnimation(zoomIn);
```

XML file R.anim.iv_zoom_in_1_finger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true">

<scale
    android:duration="750"

    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"

    android:pivotX="0"
    android:pivotY="32%"

    android:toXScale="3.5"
    android:toYScale="3.5"

    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>
</set>
```

For ivRingPinky I create canvas (the same size as ImageView) with bitmap image from drawable:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.RingOnPinky), 23*density, 32*density, false);
    Bitmap imageSize = Bitmap.createBitmap(ivRingPinky.getWidth(), ivRingPinky.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageSize);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, null);
    ivRingPinky.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), imageSize));
```

And xCoord, yCoord are here as coordinates to place the bitmap on background ImageView (ivBgHand) on finger (pinky finger in this case):

```
    float xCoord = 86.399994, yCoord = 908.96;
```

The problem arises when I hit onTouch() and drag the ivRingPinky with bitmap image on it and it moves crazy fast, I understand the reason as I have made a ScaleAnimation (zoom in). But is there any solution to make it more slowly but still smooth?